# Transferred domain name - everyone can see it but me

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, domain-name

Last week I transferred a domain name from Wordpress.com to IONOS.

It took at least 6 days to transfer but I know it has as my client is able to see it. Unfortunately I cannot.

I know it takes a while to update across the whole of the internet, but my client has been able to see the site for at least two days now and needs me to make some changes to the website.

As I'm unable to see the site I obviously can't do the work.

I've tried clearing my cache, viewing the site on multiple devices, using the wi-fi and my mobile data, and even used a VPN to change my location, but still nothing.

Is there anything that I'm able to do to get the website to appear for me? I'm worried that it never will and I won't be able to finish the work I was commissioned to do.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried clearing my cache, and viewing the website on multiple devices using more than one internet connect (wi-fi and mobile data), and a VPN to change my location.